# React.js Toggle content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.js. I'm trying to toggle (hide/show) between all categories to the selected subcategory. The code below is almost working. What's currently happening with the code below is when a category is clicked, that selected category hides and its subcategories show, however, the unclicked categories also show. I need the unclicked categories to also hide. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
class CategoryNav extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  hasCategorySelected: false,
  activeElement: "category"
}
}

toggleElement(element) {
    if (this.state.hasCategorySelected === false) {
      this.setState({
        hasCategorySelected: true,
        activeElement: "subcategory"
      });
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        hasCategorySelected: false,
        activeElement: "category"
      });
    }

  }

render() {
if (this.state.activeElement === "category") {
    return (
      <div>
      <BC.Section spacing="mini" className={this.state.activeElement === "category" ? 'bc-hidden' : 'active'}>
        <a onClick={this.toggleElement.bind(this, "subcategory")}>
            <BC.Text textColor="secondary">{this.props.category}</BC.Text>
        </a>
      </BC.Section>

      </div>

    )
  }else {
    return (
      <div>
      <BC.Section className={this.state.activeElement === "category" ? 'active' : 'bc-hidden'}>
          <a onClick={this.toggleElement.bind(this, "category")}>
              <BC.Section spacing="mini">
                <BC.Icon iconType="chevron-left" textColor="secondary" />
                <BC.Text textColor="secondary" textSize="small">Back to Categories</BC.Text>
              </BC.Section>
          </a>
          <BC.Heading headingLevel={3} spacing="mini" textColor="secondary">{this.props.category}</BC.Heading>
          <div>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
      </BC.Section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
}
```